# adequate solution to hand over variables in nested functions (in ruby)

Tags: ruby, function, variables, nested

I have several `step_1`-methods which are based on `x` and `y` variables.

`step_2` creates new methods based on `step_1`-methods but the variables aren't  needed (just passed through)!

The same goes for `step_3` (based on `step_2`-methods).

My problem is I have about 20 `step_2`-methods which consists dozens of `step_1`-methods (5 differents kinds). And for each one I have to pass the same two variables.
I need this kind of construction for iteration purposes.

Now, is there a way to hand over the variables directly form `step_3(x, y)` to `step_1 (x, y)` without using global variables?

```
# example

def step_1 (x, y)
  return x + y
end

def step_2 (*foo)
  return step_1(*foo)
end

def step_3 (*foo)
    return step_2(*foo)
end

x, y = 2, 2 # example

puts step_3(x, y) # ==> 4
```

Thanks for any suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I read "I have to pass the same two variables", this naturally brings to mind the idea of creating a simple container you can pass around instead:

```
class NumberTuple
  attr_accessor :x
  attr_accessor :y

  def initialize(x, y)
    @x = x
    @y = y
  end
end

tuple = NumberTuple.new(2,2)
step_3(tuple)
```

This often leads to the conclusion that creating a simple calculation class that can internalize all of this state. That's what class instances excel at:

```
class NumberCalculator
  def initialize(x, y)
    @x = x
    @y = y
  end

  def step_3
    step_2
  end

  def step_2
    step_1
  end

  def step_1
    @x + @y
  end
end

calculator = NumberCalculator.new(2,2)
calculator.step_3
```

Comment: It looks promising. I'll try out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
alias step_3 :step_1
```

or if you want to go through intermediate steps,

```
alias step_2 :step_1
alias step_3 :step_2
```

Comment: I don't really understand how it works and how to integrate in my example. Could you give me a clue?

Comment: I should think you wouldn't want to mix symbols and constants. I'd do `alias :step_2 :step_1` instead. But while I think your answer works for the particular example @ericMTR offered, it doesn't work in more general cases where `step_1`, `step_2`, and `step_3` don't do exactly the same thing -- just involve the same variables.

@ericMTR: `alias :x :y` basically makes it so that you can call method `y` as if it were named `x` instead.